# Alternatives for Zhongpower ZM2V0512D

Tags: dc-to-dc

Im having trouble looking for an alternative part for **Zhongpower ZM2V0512D** as I need one for a DAC I'm trying to repair. Manufacturer told me they only sell 500 pcs minimum and I only need one. I've found one (*at least I think*) called **MEV1S0512DC** but  I'm not too sure as I dont know these kind of stuff. Any other alternatives or help is welcomed!

5v input
12v output
DIP
Dual Output

**###After Researching More Found Alternatives###**:

MEV1D0512DC (*To Be Discontinued*)

NMV0512DC (*Recommended In Production*)

Here is the official link for the part: [ZM2V0512D](http://www.zhongpower.com/Products/Show_295.html)

Link to Schematics: [ZM2V0512D PDF](http://www.zhongpower.com/Upload/Files/20170904/f68e63fdc35344f8b5397d6d1c5085dd.pdf)

Link to MEV1D0512DC: [MuRata Power](https://www.murata.com/products/productdetail?partno=MEV1D0512DC)

Link to NMV0512DC: [MuRata Power](https://www.murata.com/products/productdetail?partno=NMV0512DC)

Link to Murata Updated PDF: [MuRata Power](https://www.murata.com/products/productdata/8807029899294/kdc-mev.pdf?1583754812000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the Dual (D) MEV1D0512SC.

Specs look better as long as pins are the same location. Good match.

ZM2V0512S/D 513 mW ±12V ±9 mA min  ±83 mA max

[image]
DIP  Dual Inline Pins
Have greater current capacity and higher efficiency at rated load.

Appears to be a good match at a quick glance.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it for me! Looked at the pins and they look the same and have the correct pin info. Ill order and try it out thank you again